# Should we include "flame-war" questions to have something to point users to?

Tags: discussion

Questions like "vim or emacs" and "which linux distribution" will come up repeatedly after the beta.

Should we just close those as off-topic, or have canonical questions/answers for those?

See for example [serverfault canonical answers thread](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1986/what-are-the-canonical-answers-weve-discovered-over-the-years). Similarly, other Stack Exchange sites have special questions that are for historical curiosity or to answer really popular questions that are still off-topic.

Comment: Hey, [Vim vs Emacs doesn't have to be a flamewar!](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/986/vim-vs-emacs-and-no-this-is-not-a-flame-war)

Comment: Yep, as Vim is obviously the winner. :)

Comment: And that's surprisingly good thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The serverfault canonical answers are answers to **good** questions.

While it is not entirely decided yet, it seems that [X vs. Y questions are deemed bad questions](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69/is-tool-x-versus-tool-y-a-fair-question).

I don't think we should create "canonical bad questions", as some users would not understand their "canonical bad" aspect, and would cite them as examples.

Answer (score 4):

We should close them as "too broad" or "opinion based". A good narrow scoped question "How to setup a linux that matches Windows XP most closely" is a good question. "Whats the best desktop linux distro" is not.