# "Java IDE" questions - you're doing it wrong

Tags: discussion

I disagree with closing this question: [IntelliJ IDEA vs Eclipse vs NetBeans for "pure Java" development](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/263/intellij-idea-vs-eclipse-vs-netbeans-for-pure-java-development)

I need to refer to my previous post again: [Is tool x versus tool y a fair question?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69/is-tool-x-versus-tool-y-a-fair-question) (lowest answer)

Another question about Java IDE - [Java IDE that is compatible with git](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/408/java-ide-that-is-compatible-with-git) - is also closed as too board, but interesting thing is that adding arbitrary number of additional restrictions won't make this question narrower: there would still be three answers - about IDEA, Eclipse and NetBeans, each full of epithets like "great", "powerful", "convenient", etc.

During the private beta, most elaborate answer would be most upvoted, after opening the site answer about Eclipse will outscore others because this IDE is the most popular.

**Your formalism won't help anyone to make a conscious choice of Java IDE.**

BTW I don't like answer by Ivaylo Slavov for my question. Because it's unclear and won't help me if I chose Java IDE indeed. I didn't upvote it, neither downvoted, though. I was disappointed a bit it is so high scored, because this would discourage people to write their better answers. Now the question is closed...

Answer (score 3):

I agree that most `Java IDE` questing will turn up this three choices, but still the kind of question is not legitimate. The goal of the questions here is to find the fittest tool for a given set of requirements. Take the closed answer of yours, which one would be the **correct** answer to this? One that does a throughly comparison of all three, but that is not a recommendation.

So in short: If the best possible answer to a question is not a recommendation, its not a legitimate question inside the scope of a recommendation site.

And I think we shouldn't treat Editors/IDEs differently because there are a lot of situations where there are three or four common answers. {Photoshop, Gimp, DamnIForgotOne} are the common pixel editors. {Inkscape, Illustrator, CoralDraw} are the common vector graphic tools. Same goes for all other "professional style" programs as well. "Our" tools are no different then that of other professionals who work primary on computers.
The only reason there are more different code editors is this: ([Most Writers are Writers on TvTropes.org](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MostWritersAreWriters))

Also: While the answers {Eclipse, Netbeans, IDEA...} stay the same the argumentation why THIS one is best HERE should change. And if it does not and the answers are just copy/paste then they are bad.

Comment: People who want a Java IDE recommendation should test these three very known IDE before asking. Every SE site requires that askers make some search/tests before coming here. So there is no use to recommend these very known IDE.

Comment: @Fractaliste I disagree. Each of that editors takes getting-used-to of about a month. If I have to test software for three months before asking a question, this site is useless.

Comment: There is no *correct*  answer for my question as well as for significant  fraction of questions on this site. But there could be better and worse answers

Comment: There should be one. Each "I need a tool that does X" question has at least one correct question that helped the questioner most / included the tool that he chose in the end. Your question can't have a correct question by the very design of it.