# Is this a software comparison question?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

I want to know what the pros and cons are between using PortableApps.com portables versus just using the portable apps. (A lot of programmes can be downloaded in a self-contained zip file.) So my questions are this:

- Would this be considered a "software comparison" question?
- Either way, would this be the right site to ask it?
- If not, then what site would be better?

I've already done my best to search on my own, both via StackExchange and a standard Google search. I also have already read the answer given on [this thread](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69/is-tool-x-versus-tool-y-a-fair-question), and I know it's very much dependent on a specific user's circumstances, needs and requirements, as well as what hardware they're running. All those details I would, if needed, include in the question.

I'm just unsure whether it qualifies as a software comparison question. I just want to know the pros and cons of them, and which one I should do for my own particular needs. I'm just learning about portable apps and think they're amazing, but don't have time to spend hours research every little minute detail. I've researched what I can, but there's only so much I've been able to find.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sorry, this question would not be a good fit for this site. We cater for questions of the form “what software can I use to do …?”. Comparing method A and method B, or evaluating software S, is not our job.

“I want to know the pros and cons” isn't a good format on Stack Exchange in general. But “is it suitable for this scenario?” is. Since you have a specific choice of software in mind, your question is off-topic here, but would be on-topic on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate your answer.