# Should software and OS license comparison questions be off topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

I am specifically wondering if this question should or should not be allowed?  I never heard back from any mods on this one.  If it is off-topic is there anywhere on the stack exchange network where it would not be considered off topic?

[Which Windows Server License Would be Most Cost Effective?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/34584/which-windows-server-license-would-be-most-cost-effective)

Comment: None of the answers seem to specify a place where this question should be answered instead.

Answer (score 4):

I reopened it before seeing that there was an ongoing meta discussion, so here's my rationale:

1. The question in [its current form](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/revisions/34584/5) seems to be specific enough (after being edited) that I wouldn't have closed it in the first place.
2. Licenses, especially in cases involving Microsoft, often seem to change a product in many (sometimes confusing) ways. In this case, there are [at least four basic options](http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/3/9/F39124F7-0177-463C-8A08-582463F96C9D/Windows_Server_2012_R2_Licensing_Datasheet.pdf) (PDF download), and there seem to be additional convolutions based on the number of cores, etc. that you need to support. I could make an argument that they're actually *different products*.

Based on the complexity of the choice, I believe that, at least in this case, the question is a good fit and is something we can help with. You seem to have a remarkably specific question, with budget details - and one of the specifications happens to be that it 'needs to be Windows Server'.

I don't see anything wrong with that, but I'm up for discussion on it.

Comment: I agree, Licenses (when dealing with Microsoft) really act as separate software, each having more or less features than the other. Should someone rename the title of this question as it doesn't really ask about licenses in general but rather asking for licenses in regard to Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

My *feeling* is it's not a good fit. For one, we don't do "software comparison" either (see: [Is tool x versus tool y a fair question?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/69/185)) – and for the other, it's not asking for "software meeting specific requirements", but "which license should I use for software X" (to keep it abstract).

These are the reasons why I didn't reopen it (though normally I try to be as fast with reopening as I am with closing in such cases): it simply doesn't feel right for me. Others might see this differently, so I'm glad you've brought this up here at Meta. Let's see how the community argues – which I will of course accept then :)

Comment: This also brings up my broader feelings on stack exchange where I often have a question that doesn't quite fit anywhere because of the strictness of every stack exchange. I too often find myself on meta discussing the legitimacy of question rather than spending time on what I should be doing which is trying to actually answer the question. The whole thing feels like I'm stuck in a Vogon Bureaucracy. Also they want to make a Software Comparisons stack exchange instead of merging it here? There already so many tech related SE's and even then I still have a question that falls through the cracks.

Comment: I know this might sound disappointing – but somewhere a line must be drawn. It's a fact that there isn't an SE site for everything, some things simply "fall through the cracks" as you put it. That said, let me emphasize again that above is *my personal* opinion – I wouldn't "cry up" if the community (or a co-mod) decides otherwise (wouldn't be for the first time the community takes a different stance than I had taken, and I've always respected that. A mod is not a ruler, but a servant ;)